# Why `$count--` were executed for 9 times?

Tags: php, recursion

Type `php -a` into interactive mode,it is no matter to execute in apache.

```
function recursion(){
    static $count = 0;
    $count++;
    echo $count."  ";
    if($count < 10){
        recursion();
    }
    echo $count."  ";
    $count--;
}
```

recursion();
1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10  10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1

The exit condition is `if($count < 10){` ,why the result is not
1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10 10 ?

Why `$count--` were executed for 9 times?

Comment: You recurse into your function 10 times. Each call of the function terminates and executes the line `$count--`. Where do you expect execution continues when an inner function reaches its end and returns? Of course in the calling scope, as always. Here that is the same function, since it is a recursive algorithm. The outer functions are processed to the end too...

Comment: because on `10` `if` condition not getting executed and hens   `$count--` get executed and it become `<10` again and code continues

Comment: I'm curious why the code stops at 1, why does it not infinitely recurse?

Comment: @mulquin It only recurses 10 times because it only recurses as count is increasing. Once count reaches 10 the recursion starts unwinding (and the numbers echoed start decreasing)

Answer (score 0):

Add return to stop further function execution

```
function recursion(){
    static $count = 0;
    $count++;
    echo $count."  ";
    if($count < 10){
        recursion();
        return;
    }
    echo $count."  ";
    $count--;
}
```

Output:

```
1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10  10
```

Comment: Why in your case the result is not `1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10` ?

Comment: Because "return;" is inside if statement, if you put return after if statement than you will get `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10`

Answer (score 0):

If you want 1 to 10 dont decrease after recursion:

```
<?php
function recursion(){
    static $count = 0;
    $count++;
    echo $count."  ";
    if ($count < 10) {
        recursion();
    }
}
```

Why does it behave this way?

Because it will loop **10** times incrementing each time, and by the time it gets to

```
echo $count."  ";
$count--;
```

It would have stopped nesting, and then each call to the above would decrement the value.

```
0-1
  +2
   +3
    +4
     +5
      +6
       +7
        +8
         +9
          +10
 <--------+
 12345678910
```

---

You get `1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10  10` if you return as shown in @VitalijsG because it loops 10 times but returns on all but the 10th loop, so it only hits:

```
echo $count."  ";
$count--;
```

once...